# implicit declaration error linked lists C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've got this piece of code about linked lists in C; I'm getting a previous implicit declaration error and a few warnings.

```
void append(list *head, int data)
{
    list current_node = (*head);
    while(current_node->next!=NULL)current_node = current_node->next;
    link_node(current_node, data);
}

void link_node(list *current_node, int data)
{
    list new_node = create_node();
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    (*current_node)->next = new_node;   
    *current_node = new_node;
}
```

the error message I'm getting is:

```
tp3.c: In function ‘append’:
tp3.c:42:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘link_node’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  link_node(&current_node, data);
  ^
tp3.c: At top level:
tp3.c:44:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘link_node’
 void link_node(list *current_node, int data)
      ^
tp3.c:42:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘link_node’ was here
  link_node(&current_node, data);
```

I feel like I lack knowledge in the matter of pointers and how to use them, could you suggest any online free resources(I am a self-thought).

Comment: Put your `link_node` function before the `append` function. Or declare the function beforehand by putting `void link_node(list *current_node, int data);` at the top.

Comment: @Blaze I did now I'm getting 'expected struct node **' but arg is of type *. When I change it to that I get lot more errors!

Comment: Looks like fixing that error just exposed even more errors. Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: @Blaze I think the error is only in the code above because when I use only link node and do the loop manually in the main function the code works just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler reads the code from top to bottom. It must see the declaration of a name before you use it, or else it will assume an implicit type for it. Here you use (call) the function `link_node` on line 42, but the function is both defined and declared at line 44. Hence the compiler doesn't know about the upcoming declaration when it's on line 42, assumes an implicit type for it, and then warns on line 44 that the assumption didn't match the actual type.

Simply declare the function somewhere above the first place where you use it, with:

```
void link_node(list *current_node, int data);
```

edit: As for your second issue, you are passing `list` where the type of the argument is `list *`, i.e., pointer to list. You have shot yourself in the foot by obfuscating the pointer when you have `typedef`ed `list` as `struct node *`, so when `list *current_node` looks like a pointer to list, it is in fact a pointer to a pointer to a node, i.e, two levels of indirection.

Passing `&current_node` would technically fix the error but it wouldn't do what you want (because `link_node` could then modify your local variable `current_node`, which would not modify the list itself). The solution to that would be to use `list *current_node` as your local variable so you don't lose a level of indirection.

*However*, it looks like your `link_node` function is broken anyways, and doesn't currently need the pointer to pointer, so you could change the argument's type to just `list` and only set the `next` link of that node. (But doing that means it cannot link to an empty list, so you need a sentinel node that's always there, or rethink the whole function. But remember that it's currently broken…)

Comment: I did now I'm getting 'expected struct node **' but arg is of type *. When I change it to that, I get a lot more errors!

Answer (score 1):

In your `append()` method try replacing `list current_node = (*head);` with `list *current_node = head;`. It should resolve the issue.